# AllowHtml attribute not working on production

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I have a model that required that html be captured. I have added the [AllowHtml] attribute to the model property and it works correctly on my local server when debugging.

Once deployed to production however, it works correctly when executed on the production server (i.e. I remote onto the server and browse it there), but fails with the the usual "potentially dangerous blah blah blah " message when executed from any other machine.

So it seems to me that there is something to do with the location involved in the validation, or am I completely missing the boat.

Just to confirm, I have made no "special" changes to the web.config.

Please can someone explain why I am having this issue.

Model

```
[AllowHtml]
[Display(Name = "Overview")]
public string Overview { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
//
// POST: /Product/
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditFeature(BackOffice.Models.ProductFeature model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //insert the new product
        }
        //invalid model, return with errors
        return View(model);
 }
```

View

```
@model BackOffice.Models.ProductFeature

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFeature", "Product", null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.Hidden("ProductID", @Model.ProductID)

    <div class="modal fade" id="FeatureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="FeatureModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add a Feature</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='col-lg-2 control-label'>Title</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='col-lg-2 control-label'>Overview</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, 10, 40, new { @class = "ckeditor", id = "overview" })
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='clearfix'></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
}
```

Comment: The model used in EDIT and ADD are the same?

Comment: @Romias Yes they are the same, and they both fail on insert / update when called from a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mis-match in the method names here. You have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFeature", "Product", null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
}
```

But Your action method is called

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditFeature(BackOffice.Models.ProductFeature model)
{
}
```

Where is the **AddFeature** action method?